# Why is this polynomial a function of $X^3$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

In studying that recent [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396915/how-does-one-evaluate-sqrtx-y-sqrtx-y/404795#404795), I noticed that curious (or perhaps
not so curious) property : if $x,y$ are rational numbers and $a$ is the real
part of a cubic root of $x+iy$, then $Q(a^3)=0$ where $Q$ is a polynomial
of degree three with rational coefficients.

This is a purely algebraic property, and I obtained it by calculating some
resultants with my computer.

Now, can we show  *a priori* that $a$ is annihilated by a 
polynomial of this form, without computer-made computations ? Note that
this property does not hold for the imaginary part of a cubic root.

Comment: $Q$ is any polynomial? If $Q(a^3) = 0$, then $P = Q+1$ is a polynomial of degree three with rational coefficients, but $P(a^3)=1$.

Comment: @WillNelson Of course not, $Q$ is a uniquely defined polynomial (namely $64T^3 - 48xT^2 + (-15x^2 - 27y^2)T- x^3$, but I left that out in the question to insist that I only need a proof of the existence of $Q$, not its actual value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the solutions to the system $(a+b)^3 = x+y, (a-b)^3 = x-y$, are the $9$ couples that you obtain by choosing a complex cube root $u$ of $x+y$, a complex cube root $v$ of $x-y$, and set $a=(u+v)/2, b = (u-v)/2$ (this is clear after a change of variables)

Since you can multiply both $u$ and $v$ by the same cube root of $1$ to obtain new solutions,
if $(a,b)$ is a solution, so are $(\zeta_3a,\zeta_3b)$ and $(\zeta_3^2 a, \zeta_3^2 b)$, hence the degree $9$ polynomial for $a$ is in fact a polynomial in $a^3$ (and of course the same goes with the one for $b$)

Comment: It is also clear that the property extends to any degree : the real part $a$ of a nth root of $x+iy$ will be annihilated by a polynomial of degree $n^2$, that can be written as a function of $a^n$.