# Rewritting a messy cubic root

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there a really quick way of showing that:

$$\sqrt[3]{49-25\sqrt{2}}$$

Can be written in the form:

$$a+b\sqrt{2}$$

Is there a way to generalize which integers $a$ and $b$ can be rewritten in such a way?

Comment: Why do you think it is possible to write that cubic root in that way?

Comment: @DonAntonio I was able to do the algebra out (ie setting the expression equal to a+bsqrt2 and setting parts equal to one another.) I was also given the hint that a and b are integers so I was able to do some factoring along the way.

Comment: One way is to notice that the [minimum polynomial](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+polynomial+%2845+-+29sqrt%282%29%29^%281%2F3%29) has degree $2$, so there's at least hope for this to be true; if the degree was higher than $2$, it's not possible.

Comment: Then what are you asking, @Jackson: how to do it "quickly"? Perhaps you show your work to know what'd be "quickly" in this case...

Comment: @Don Because it is, viz. $\ 3 -\sqrt{2}\ \ $

Comment: That I know, @BillDubuque: the question is how *the OP* suspected, or knew, that it is so.

Comment: @DonAntonio I was wondering if there was some sort of characteristic of these numbers that guaranteed this outcome. I solved it the standard algebra way (45=a^3-6ab^2 and 29=3a^2b+2b^3). Since I was given in the problem that a and b were integers, I used the fact that 29 is prime to determine a and b.

Comment: @Jackson See my answer below for a generalization.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does one evaluate $\sqrt{x + y} + \sqrt{x - y}$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396915/how-does-one-evaluate-sqrtx-y-sqrtx-y)

Answer (score 9):

If we assume $\sqrt[3]{45 - 29 \sqrt{2}} = a + b \sqrt{2}$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, then cubing both sides and expanding gives us $a^3 + 3 a^2 b \sqrt{2} + 6 a b^2 + 2 b^3 \sqrt{2}$, so we want to solve $$\eqalign{a^3 + 6 a b^2 &= 45\cr
3 a^2 b + 2 b^3 &= -29\cr}$$
Now $b$ divides $3 a^2 b + 2 b^3$ and $29$ is prime, so $b$ must be $\pm 1$.
Moreover $b = +1$ would make $3 a^2 + 2 b^3 > 0$, so we must have $b = -1$.
Then the second equation becomes $-3 a^2 - 2 = -29$ or $a^2 = 9$, so $a = \pm 3$.  Finally the first equation becomes $\pm 27 \pm 18 = 45$ which is true for $a=+3$.  Thus the answer is $3 - \sqrt{2}$.

EDIT: The problem keeps getting edited, but here are some more general considerations.
For $\sqrt[3]{A + B \sqrt{m}} = a + b \sqrt{m}$ where $m$ is a square-free integer, 
you need
$$ \eqalign{ a (a^2 + 3 m b^2) &= A\cr
             b (3 a^2 + m b^2) &= B\cr}$$ 
so $a$ divides $A$ and $b$ divides $B$.   That reduces you to finitely many
possibilities.  To cut it down further you might note that $a \equiv A \mod 3$ and $mb\equiv B \mod 3$, and (if $m > 0$) $a$ and $b$ have the same signs as $A$ and $B$ respectively.
Also, $$ A^2 - B^2 m = (a^2 - b^2 m)^3$$
so a necessary condition for this to work is that $A^2 - B^2 m$ is the cube of an integer.  For example, $49^2 - 2 \times 25^2 = 1151 $ is not the cube of an integer, so $49 - 25 \sqrt{2}$ won't work.

Comment: The OP already solved it that way, see the comments to the question. He's asking about generalizations.

Comment: I see the OP has now changed the question to $45 + 25 \sqrt{2}$.  This one does not simplify.

Comment: @Robert Sorry, I think somebody else mistakenly edited it. Good catch.

Comment: ... and now it's changed again, to $49 - 25 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes I fixed it back. At some point, somebody even edited to say a+sqrtb, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: And $\ 4\mid A/a+B/b,\ $ indeed $\ (A/a+B/b)/4 = a^2+mb^2 \ \ $

Comment: And $\ (B/b - A/a)/2 = a^2-mb^2 = \alpha\alpha'\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque: your idea is creative.

Comment: How do you know that $b\equiv B\pmod 3$? Could you show me the proof? Thanks.

Comment: @mathh $\ {\rm mod}\ 3\!:\ A = a^3 + 3mab^2 \equiv a^3 \equiv a\ $ by little Fermat. Similarly $\ B\equiv mb\ $ (originally it mistakenly read $\ B\equiv b,\ $ so maybe that caused confusion).