# How to show this equals 1 without "calculations"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

We have $$ \sqrt[3]{2 +\sqrt{5}} + \sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}} = 1 $$

Is there any way we can get this results through algebraic manipulations rather than just plugging it into a calculator?

Of course, $(2 +\sqrt{5}) + (2-\sqrt{5}) = 4 $, maybe this can in some way help?

Comment: Have you tried cubing the LHS using $(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^2+b^3$ ? After a bit of algebraic work, it comes out quite nicely.

Comment: @GuillermoAngeris I tried, but it didn't work out, I end up with the same problem

Comment: @thanasissdr Why not?

Comment: @thanasissdr Well, this question arises from trying to find the roots of a cubic function.

Comment: @thanasissdr Also, it is a cube root.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396915/how-does-one-evaluate-sqrt3x-iy-sqrt3x-iy?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}}$ $b=\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}$. Obviously $a b =-1$. 
Now let's forget what values of $a$ and $b$ and solve the system: 
$$
ab=-1\\
a+b=1
$$
They imply
$$
a^2-a-1=0
$$
namely $a=\frac {1\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$. So $a=\frac {1+\sqrt{5}}{2}, b=\frac {1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now taking $a^3,b^3$ we can easily get $2\pm\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: How do they imply that? I can't see it

Comment: $ab=-1\to a(1-a)=-1\to a^2-a-1=0$

Comment: This reasoning seems circular to me, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Knowning that $ab=-1$ I am looking for $a,b$ such that $a+b=1$. This is quadratic equation with roots easily calculated. The cube of these roots is calculated easily too.

Comment: I understand that $ab=-1$. But I don't understand why you can state $a+b=1$. How can you be looking for $a,b$ when you already defined them?

Comment: Forget what I defined. I am not using the values of $a,b$ I only using the fact that $ab=-1$. And looking for solutions when $a+b=1$. It turns out out that they what we need.

Comment: No. $\sqrt[3] {(2+\sqrt{5})(2-\sqrt{5})}=\sqrt[3] {4-5}=\sqrt[3] {-1}=-1$.

Comment: Are you kidding?

Comment: yes, I am. Thanks for the help btw

Answer (score 5):

$u^3=2+\sqrt 5$, $v^3=2-\sqrt 5$

$u^3v^3=4-5=-1$ so $uv=-1$.

$u^3+v^3=4$

$(u+v)^3=u^3+v^3+3uv(u+v)=4-3(u+v)$.

That is, $u+v$ is *a* root of the equation $X^3+3X-4=0$ (1). The derivative of this polynomial is $3X^2+3$ which has no roots. By Rolle's theorem, that means that (1) has only one real root. You can easily check that $1$ is that root.

Comment: I don't understand. Exactly what is attained using Cardano? I haven't used Cardano. Should I (you)?

Comment: I used Cardano to obtain a root of the equation you mentioned, and I knew beforehand that 1 was a root. What I'm trying to do now is show that the 2 roots are equivalent.

Comment: Ah, ok. You want to know how to obtain this $1$ with no previous knowledge of that $1$ is a root. Well, Gauss called this "casus irreductibilis"... I repeat: Gauss. I don't know if there is a known method to do that. But if there is, it must be really tough.

Answer (score 4):

I'll expand on Guillermo's comment: let
$$
a=\sqrt[3]{2+\sqrt{5}},\quad b=\sqrt[3]{2-\sqrt{5}}.
$$
You want to show that $a+b=1$. Consider
$$
(a+b)^3=a^3+3a^2b+3ab^3+b^3=(a^3+b^3)+3ab(a+b)=4+3\times(-1)(a+b)
$$
so if you let $x=(a+b)$ , then $x$ is a real number satisfying
$$
0=x^3+3x-4=x^3-x^2+x^2-x+4x-4\\
=(x-1)(x^2+x+4)=(x-1)\left[(x+0.5)^2+3.75\right].
$$
We infer that $x=1$.

Comment: I don't understand why $x$ is a root of that polynomial

Comment: Because in the line before that claim, I demonstrated that $$x^3=(a+b)^3=4-3(a+b)=4-3x$$ which implies $x^3+3x-4=0$.

Comment: Actually, I'll edit the solution so that the word "root" won't even be mentioned.