# How to generate complicated looking identities such as $\sqrt [3] {2 + \sqrt 5} - \sqrt [3] {2 - \sqrt 5}=1$ easily?

Tags: soft-question, philosophy

How to generate complicated looking identities, or even more complicated looking identies such as $\sqrt [3] {2 + \sqrt 5} - \sqrt [3] {2 - \sqrt 5}=1$ easily?

I saw the identity to be shown. What is I think would be more interesting would be the origin of what ever it is that can produce even more complicated looking identities with relative ease (by relative ease I mean subbing a value and generating the identity in a mechanical fashion, no matter how laborious or long that procedure takes)

Comment: It helps that $\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^3 = 2 + \sqrt{5}, \left(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^3 = 2 - \sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Here's another one: $$\sqrt{1+2\sqrt{1+3\sqrt{1+\ldots}}}=3$$

Comment: But in general, I don't think there's any such way to "generate" complicated results. Because not every result has the same origin.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : holy hell, what generates identities like that?

Comment: That's actually a result proved by Ramanujan.

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : yes I agree nothing can be that general, is there even a taxonomy of identies or the their generating families exist?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas : that specific result or a more general form that makes that as a specific value?

Comment: Check out the answers posted by me and YoTengoUnLCD that provides somewhat of an useful answer to your question.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/937073

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's a nice "generator" of the result I commented in the comments.

Comment: Plugging $x=2,n=1,a=0$ gives us the specific result of the problem that Ramanujan posed.

Answer (score 2):

An example:
$$
1=\sqrt{2-1} \longrightarrow1=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-1}}
$$
Repeat infinitely many times:
$$
1=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2...}}}}
$$

You can check this is true:
$$
x=\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2-\sqrt{2...}}}} \longrightarrow x=\sqrt{2-x}
$$
$$
x^2=2-x \longrightarrow x_1=1
$$
$x_2=-2$ can be discarded as we're taking a square root.

It's worth to note that what Prasun Biswas and I have posted here are expressions called "nested radicals".

Ramanujan was a mathematician that greatly raised interest and got some great conclusions about them at his time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical is worth a look.